# Ubuntu 16.04 stuck on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

When I try to boot Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire laptop, it gets stuck at this black screen.

[image]

I'm dual booting with Windows 10.

This only started happening today after I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F10 because I thought it was a shortcut in the program I was in, but it wasn't. It caused the screen to go black so I was forced to shutdown my laptop and I've been having this boot issue ever since.